# Specify that an object doesn't receive any messages in RSpec

Tags: ruby, rspec

I know how to specify that an object shouldn't receive a specific message:

```
expect(File).to_not receive(:delete)
```

How would I specify that it shouldn't receive any messages at all? Something like

```
expect(File).to_not receive_any_message
```

Comment: What is the context here? Why would you ever need to do this?

Comment: I wanted to do this to test a no-op, i.e. nothing created, updated, deleted etc.

Comment: My use case for wanting this is ensuring that there are no side effects when a guard condition is true. e.g. `return unless user.country == COUNTRY_USA` at the top of a method.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Sounds like you just want to replace the object in question with a double on which you have defined no expectations (so any method call would result in an error). In your exact case you could do

```
stub_const("File", double())
```

Comment: Well, if you call `File.to_s` it won't fail, it will return
=> "#[Double (anonymous)]"

Comment: Why not `hide_const("File")`? https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/mutating-constants/hide-defined-constant

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what the use-case would be. But the following is the only direct answer I can come up with:

```
methods_list = File.public_methods # using 'public_methods' for clarity
methods_list.each do |method_name|
  expect(File).to_not receive(method_name)
end
```

In case you want to cover all methods (i.e. not just the `public` ones):

```
# readers, let me know if there is a single method to
# fetch all public, protected, and private methods
methods_list = File.public_methods +
               File.protected_methods +
               File.private_methods
```

Comment: I have a usecase which might be worth sharing, I hope. I expose a service in a module on module level and want to assure that the service is not soliciated in case of an error detected on the input data. By forbidding any message to be sent to that service I get rid of connascence by name (as so well explained by the late Jim Weirich) and my tests are not brittle relative to an API change in the service.